# how to use group by in update form ? in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

first, I search name who teaches more than 2 courses

```
SELECT i.name, COUNT(*) teaches FROM instructor i
INNER JOIN teaches t ON i.id = t.id
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*)>=2;
```

and it's working so I want to raise salary with these results

```
UPDATE i SET salary = salary*1.05
FROM instructor i
INNER JOIN teaches t ON i.id = t.id
GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*)>=2;
```

but an error in SQL syntax; how to fix it?

Comment: What _version_ of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: i use MYSQL, MariaDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an update join here:

```sql
UPDATE instructor t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT i.id
    FROM instructor i
    INNER JOIN teaches t ON i.id = t.id
    GROUP BY i.id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
SET
    salary = 1.05 * salary;
```

Comment: thx for comment ! i have to learn more about inner join..